# Verilog macro expansion

Tags: macros, verilog, system-verilog

Is there any tool (e.g., ncverilog, VCS, synplify, vivado, etc.) that lets you see the expanded output of a Verilog or SystemVerilog macro?

I'm about to write a script to parse macros and manually expand them, in order to debug some macros written by someone else. If there's some tool that can do this already, I'd be happy to use that tool instead.

Comment: Mentor's Questa or Modelsim has the capability to do this but I don't know the command off hand.

Comment: Many modern IDE have provided this feature, such as VCS-DVE, INCISIV-SimVision, Questa/Modelsim, Verdi, Conformal, etc., and you might look into the manual to see how to use it.
However, there is still one issue when you need to debug macros because many people like to intensively use macro in macro. It is hard to debug or figure out the problem when you only see the final expansion string. And you might need to reword the question.

Comment: Does this involve UVM/OVM? You'll need a full lexer, including the conditional compilation directives, to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VCS-DVE allows you to expand macros in a debug session, just click on the + next to the macro you want to see:

[image]